# Getting the values of many defaultdicts that contains a certain key

Tags: python, dictionary, key, defaultdict

I have several `defaultdict` that looks like this:

```
en1 = {1:['handler', 'coach', 'manager'],2:['a','c']}
es2 = {1:['entrenador', 'míster', 'entrenadora'],2:['h','i'],4:['j','k','m']}
it3 = {1:['mister', 'allenatore' 'coach'],3:['p','q'],5:['r','q']}
...
```

And I need get the string from each defaultdict sharing the same index. Something like this:

```
for i in en1:
  for j in en1[i]:
    for k in es2[i]:
      for l in it3[i]:
        print j, k, l
```

but i have to do it for like 30+ defaultdict, so **how can that be done without write that horrendous loop above?**

**Is there a way to get all the values of the defaultdict with the same keys and then output the values easily?**

It should output combinations of tuples made up of values sharing the same key for all `dicts`, e.g.:

```
handler entrenador mister
handler entrenador allenatore
handler entrenador coach
handler mister mister
handler mister allenator
...
```

Comment: Why not store all those dictionaries in a list or dictionary instead of using local variables with incremental names?

Comment: because they came from several different inputs. If i store them as a list of dictionaries, is there a way to access the different values of the defaultdict with the same key easily?

Comment: Yes. Much, much easier.

Comment: @2er0: See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with using a *list* of dictionaries instead of 30 separate variables:

```
dd = [{1: ['a', 'b'], 2: ['a', 'c'], 3: ['d', 'e']}, {1: ['f', 'g', 'l'], 2: ['h', 'i'], 4: ['j', 'k', 'm']}, ...]
```

And use `itertools.product()` to generate all combinations between matching contained lists:

```
from itertools import product

for key in dd[0]:
    for combination in product(*(d[key] for d in dd)):
        print ' '.join(combination)
```

Here the generator expression retrieves the same key from all dictionaries in one statement.

Output for your sample input; note, there is no `dd2[3]` and no `dd3[2]`, so for keys 2 and 3 no output is generated.

```
>>> for key in dd[0]:
...     for combination in product(*(d[key] for d in dd)):
...         print ' '.join(combination)
... 
handler entrenador mister
handler entrenador allenatorecoach
handler míster mister
handler míster allenatorecoach
handler entrenadora mister
handler entrenadora allenatorecoach
coach entrenador mister
coach entrenador allenatorecoach
coach míster mister
coach míster allenatorecoach
coach entrenadora mister
coach entrenadora allenatorecoach
manager entrenador mister
manager entrenador allenatorecoach
manager míster mister
manager míster allenatorecoach
manager entrenadora mister
manager entrenadora allenatorecoach
```

Looping over many keys then producing products from 30 different lists is going to take a while. You may have to rethink what you are trying to  do and avoid doing too much work.

Comment: Note: Even if every list just has 2 values, this loop will be a billion iterations long. It may be better to avoid needing this loop at all.

Comment: @user2357112: Absolutely, but the OP is not stating what the end-goal is, so for now we can only help him with pulling a trigger. If the gun is aiming at the foot, so be it!

Comment: @2er0: Then you need to be more explicit what you expect the correct output to be. `product()` models your nested loops perfectly so if this is the wrong output, your version would have produced the same incorrect solution.

Comment: @2er0: I added a `' '.join()` to produce the same white-space separated output your post is using, but I suspect things are not that trivial.

Comment: I am generating documents from the dictionary values, looping through all values would be correct. But still, your code isn't simultaneously  outputing the values of the dictionary that shares the same key.

Comment: ;P, let me change the question to give some real examples

Comment: `d[key] for d in dd` retrieves the lists from each dictionary for the given key. Start with `print [d[key] for d in dd]` (instead of the `product` `for` loop) to see where you think things might be going wrong.

Comment: @2er0: I discovered I ommitted the `*` argument splash to `product()`; added now. A quick test run shows the code works for `1`; for `2` there is a key missing in the `dd3` dictionary so that would an be empty result. Same for `3`.

Comment: @Martijn: yep the `*` argument to product works now, thanks. No worries about the excessively looping, it was intended because i'm generating some documents purely from dictionaries =)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your expectations regarding output, ("string from each defaultdict sharing the same index"? Your sample output contains items that do not share the same index, e.g. a g a, g has second position in dd2 key1) but this will give you the dictionary containing fused values of items with the same key within all three dicts :

```
d1 = {1:['a','b'],2:['a','c'],3:['d','e']}
d2 = {1:['f','g','l'],2:['h','i'],4:['j','k','m']}
d3 = {1:['n','a'],3:['p','q'],5:['r','q']}

d4 = [d1,d2,d3]
new = {}
for i in d4:
    for m in i:
        try:
            new[m].extend(i[m])
        except:
            new[m] = []
            new[m].extend(i[m])
print new
{1: ['a', 'b', 'f', 'g', 'l', 'n', 'a'], 
 2: ['a', 'c', 'h', 'i'], 3: ['d', 'e', 'p', 'q'], 
 4: ['j', 'k', 'm'], 5: ['r', 'q']}
```

And you can then make another list containing combinations of all items in those lists if you need them.

```
from itertools import combinations
combs = []
#this is just for one key, but you can loop over list of dicts to do this for each dict
for m in combinations(new[1],3):
    perms.append(m)
print combs
[('a', 'b', 'f'), ('a', 'b', 'g'), ('a', 'b', 'l'), ('a', 'b', 'n'), ('a', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'f', 'g'), ('a', 'f', 'l'), ('a', 'f', 'n'), ('a', 'f', 'a'), ('a', 'g', 'l'), ('a', 'g', 'n'), ('a', 'g', 'a'), ('a', 'l', 'n'), ('a', 'l', 'a'), ('a', 'n', 'a'), ('b', 'f', 'g'), ('b', 'f', 'l'), ('b', 'f', 'n'), ('b', 'f', 'a'), ('b', 'g', 'l'), ('b', 'g', 'n'), ('b', 'g', 'a'), ('b', 'l', 'n'), ('b', 'l', 'a'), ('b', 'n', 'a'), ('f', 'g', 'l'), ('f', 'g', 'n'), ('f', 'g', 'a'), ('f', 'l', 'n'), ('f', 'l', 'a'), ('f', 'n', 'a'), ('g', 'l', 'n'), ('g', 'l', 'a'), ('g', 'n', 'a'), ('l', 'n', 'a')]
```

the list is long.

Comment: I Edited my answer, but honestly I don't know what you want the sample output is not very clear.